# Do I need to implement an XMPP server?

Tags: xmpp, messaging, switching

(newbie alert)

I need to program a multiparty communication service for a course project, and I am considering XMPP for it.

The service needs following messaging semantics:

1) server will provide a method of registering and unregistering an address such as `somenode@myservice.com/SomeResource`. (for now I will do it manually).

2) server will provide a method of forwarding incoming messages from, say, `somenode@myservice.com/SomeResource` to `someothernode@myservice.com/someOtherResource`, assuming that the latter is registered, and a method for removing this forwarding. (for now I will do it manually).

3) anonymous clients can send messages to, say, `somenode@myservice.com/someresource` (one way traffic only). If there is any forwarding setup, the message will be forwarded. Finally if the address is `somenode@myservice.com/someresource` is registered, the message will be stored for later delivery (or immediate if a retrieving client is online - see below). If no forwarding and unregistered, message will be silently dropped.

4) clients can connect and retrieve messages from a registered address. Exact method of authenticating clients (e.g., passwords?) is yet to be determined.

- Eventually, I want to add support for clients to connect from a web browser so they can register/unregister and set/remove forwarding themselves.

Thus, the server will have to do some non-standard switching. Will I need to implement an XMPP server for this? I guess some (or all?) of this can also be done using a XMPP client bot

Comment: UPDATE: both suggestions are good. After a lot of experimenting with Smack and susmack, I decided that writing my own custom Java server is the easiest way to go to set up a prototype running asap.

I will look into ActiveMQ. I'm fairly new to Java so other suggestions on getting started are solicited. My goal is to write minimum amount of code and to make the prototype fairly decent quality in the shortest amount of time.

Pubsub does part of what I need, but I may need to modify an existing server to get exactly what I need. Specifically, I need subscriber anonymity and anonymous publishers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might investigate whether [Pub/Sub](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html) is a better fit for your problem than custom messaging semantics.  If so, you may find an implementation of it in your existing XMPP server.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get away with using a message queue like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) for the communication and [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) for the routing/forwarding/processing.

Comment: Checking out the two. Will give feedback soon. Other answers welcome too :)